# Django inheritance and parent object related name

Tags: python, django, inheritance

I'm upgrading a project from django 1.8 to 1.10 and it looks like django has improved the check of eventual name collision between foreign keys and model inheritance. 
This is obviously a good thing, but the projet I need to upgrade is a big one and it would be a hell to rename a model.

Let me explain the problem : I have a base class called `Parent` and many children which are linked together, like so :

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10)


class ChildA(Parent):
    description = models.TextField()


class ChildB(Parent):
    description = models.TextField()
    childa = models.ForeignKey(ChildA)
```

The clash here is that a `childb` object has 2 "childa" attributes :

- The "childa" ForeignKey
- The instance inherited by the ChildA model (because childb has also the `parent` attributes).

The 2 obvious solutions here are :

- Rename the ForeignKey `ChildB.childa` to `ChildB.somethingelse`
- Rename the `ChildA` model to something else.

Both solutions costs a lot and will probably introduce new bugs. 
So I wondered : Is it possible to rename the reverse related name of the inherited object ?

For example :

```
p = Parent.objects.get(pk=1)
print p.childa_child  # Hit the ChildA instance
```

I have no idea if I'm clear enough but I'll keep this question up to date.

**==== EDIT ====**

To be more concise, if I have 2 models `class Parent(models.Model)` and `class Child(Parent)`, a dynamic attribute `parent.child` is created.

Is it possible to edit this attribute name without touching the class name ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Multi-table inheritance creates an implicit `OneToOneField` field between the base model and the subclass.

Django allows you to modify this relationship by explicitly setting the one to one field.

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10)


class ChildA(Parent):
    parent = models.OneToOneField(to=Parent, parent_link=True)
    description = models.TextField()


class ChildB(Parent):
    parent = models.OneToOneField(to=Parent, parent_link=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    childa = models.ForeignKey(ChildA)
```

The important bit here is the `parent_link=True` argument which tells Django to use this field declaration for managing the multi-table inheritance with these two models.

So you can now set `related_name='+'` to prevent Django from creating a reverse relationship or you can set `related_name` to a more unique name:

```
class ChildA(Parent):
    parent = models.OneToOneField(to=Parent, parent_link=True, related_name='child_a_here')
    description = models.TextField()


class ChildB(Parent):
    parent = models.OneToOneField(to=Parent, parent_link=True, related_name='child_b_here')
    description = models.TextField()
    childa = models.ForeignKey(ChildA)
```

Comment: That was totally it ! Thank you. 
Here is also the link to the reference in the documentation : 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#specifying-the-parent-link-field

Comment: Worked, specifically for legacy fixes you'll need to name the parent link [lowercase class name]_ptr to mimic 1.8 behavior for example:  parent_ptr = models.OneToOneField(to=Parent, parent_link=True, related_name='+') which uses the database field parent_ptr_id like version 1.8 did.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused as to how ChildB has to two ChildA links, it looks like you left out some relationship fields from the models perhaps? Regardless, what I think you are looking for is the [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) parameter.

So with:

```
class ChildB(Parent):
    description = models.TextField()
    childa = models.ForeignKey(ChildA, related_name='b_children')
```

You could do a query like so:

```
a = ChildA.objects.get(id=1)
print(a.b_children)
```

You may also be interested in [abstract models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes).

Comment: Thanks for answering.
This is not the problem. I've found the django ticket that relates this point : https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17673

The Parent model has 2 attributes "childa" and before django 1.8, it was admited to shadow one of the attribute, but with django 1.9+ it raises a SystemCheckError. 

    p = Parent.objects.get(pk=1)
    print p.childa  # Should it hit the ChildA child or the childa attribute of the the ChildB child ?

Comment: I've edited the initial post to add a more simple example.